# autoSizeColumn doesn't work with my HSSFSheet POI

Tags: jsp, apache-poi

I want to adjust the width of my columns with autoSizeColumn, but it doesn't work, any idea?

```
 Statement StReporte     = conexion.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs_marcador = StReporte.executeQuery("call sprep_reportesmensuales('2014-06-01','2014-07-01',6,2)");

    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs_marcador.getMetaData();
    int columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();



    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:/Servidorweb/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/webapps/reportes_mensuales/reporte_prueba.xls");
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.createSheet("POI Worksheet");


    int controw = 0;

    while(rs_marcador.next())
    {



            HSSFRow row = worksheet.createRow((short) controw);

            for(int i = 0; i < columnsNumber; i++)
            {
                HSSFCell cellA1 = row.createCell((short) i);
                cellA1.setCellValue(rs_marcador.getString(i+1));

            }

             worksheet.autoSizeColumn();

            controw++;

    }

        workbook.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.flush();
        fileOut.close();
```

this is the error:
The method autoSizeColumn() is undefined for the type HSSFSheet.

Comment: `worksheet.autoSizeColumn(int);` I put it inside the for with `i` and it doesn't work anyway

Comment: this should normally only be called once per column, at the end of your processing. ie. first set values to the cell, then run autoSizeColumn() in a for loop to cover all columns.

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < columnsNumber; i++)
            {
                HSSFCell cellA1 = row.createCell((short) i);
                cellA1.setCellValue(rs_marcador.getString(i+1));
                 worksheet.autoSizeColumn(i);
            }
             `

Comment: hope that's where you put values to the cells. try putting one more for loop,for(int i = 0; i < columnsNumber; i++){worksheet.autoSizeColumn(i);}. autoSizeColumn() should not be a part of first for loop

Comment: wherever I put the autoSizeColumn, the HSSFSheet doesn't recognize the method and it throws the error anyway

Comment: hope you are referring to HSSFSheet.autoSizeColumn(int) version. int param should be your column number. what's the error?

Comment: The method autoSizeColumn(int) is undefined for the type HSSFSheet

Comment: Have you made sure you have the latest version of Apache POI on your classpath, and no older POI jars to confuse things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Disclaimer: Since the OP was getting the error "The method autoSizeColumn(int) is undefined for the type HSSFSheet" I assumed an older version of the library was in use.*

The method takes a `short` not an `int` (on older versions of the library), so you have to typecast (like you are already doing with `createCell`):

```
for(int i = 0; i < columnsNumber; i++)
{
   worksheet.autoSizeColumn((short)i);
}
```

You should also wait to do this to the very end, so put it after your while loop, because inside the while loop you would be doing it many times and you only need to do it once. So put it right before `workbook.write(fileOut);`

Comment: Do I need to import something else? because it stills throwing me the error, The method autoSizeColumn(short) is undefined for the type HSSFSheet

Comment: And do I need to pass the number of columns in autoSizeColumn?

Comment: @zickno, You have to call it for each column, one at a time, hence the for loop.

Comment: @zickno, what version of the library do you have installed? Maybe you should upgrade.

Comment: 3.10.1 I'll download it again,just in case, Thanks

Comment: I imported all the jars again, and it worked!! that weird things that  just can't be explained jejeje

Answer (score 1):

From the [Apache POI JavaDocs on Sheet](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html), you'll see that the method signature of `autoSizeColumn` is that it takes [an int as a parameter](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#autoSizeColumn%28int%29), which is the column to auto size

Thus, your code which was:

```
while(rs_marcador.next())
{
        for(int i = 0; i < columnsNumber; i++)
        {
            HSSFCell cellA1 = row.createCell((short) i);
            cellA1.setCellValue(rs_marcador.getString(i+1));
        }
        worksheet.autoSizeColumn();
}
```

Instead needs to be:

```
while(rs_marcador.next())
{
        for(int i = 0; i < columnsNumber; i++)
        {
            HSSFCell cellA1 = row.createCell((short) i);
            cellA1.setCellValue(rs_marcador.getString(i+1));
        }
}
for(int i = 0; i < columnsNumber; i++)
{
        worksheet.autoSizeColumn(i);
}
```

Note that you should only auto-size the columns at the very end, as it's a fairly slow operations